# Can Eclipse CDT check grammetical errors the time I type it?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse Juno 4.2 and CDT 8.1,and they work well.But there are some problems:Eclipse can warn me some spelling mistakes,like the lack of ; and mis-spelling names.But it can's warn me mistakes like passing wrong arguments to a function,or initialising an object using illegal arguments.These can only be shown after a build.Besides,typing an include does not show effects until another build.Are there any ways to show these errors and make include available immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. CDT calls out to your compiler to find all the syntax and semantic errors.

You can get a bit more error reporting from the indexer:

- Go to Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations and turn on C/C++ Indexer Markers
- Go to Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor > Syntax Coloring, then select Code > Problems and click the Enable checkbox.

Also if you have codan turned on that should report some errors as well.